How to render threejs AR applications like VR
I created threejs application , embedded VR button , now the scene is rendered with stereoscopic images. I deployed the application and accessed same on my mobile , inserted my mobile into google cardboard , things worked as expected . I can fully enjoy the VR scene that I created.
Then instead of VR button , I added AR button . this is not creating stereoscopic images , but enables phone camera , and render 3d models in real world . If I insert my mobile in google cardboard , I see distorted scene , because the rendered scene is not with stereoscopic images so this is expected behavior .
How can I convert this AR behavior like VR experience. I have to insert my mobile in google cardboard and start the application . it should start the camera , and 3d objects should be placed on real world , later I will have to add interaction with controllers , so that user can move the 3D objects . The rendering scene should be like stereoscopic scene so that while seeing through two glasses , the user will see correct model in the real world .
Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do ? Thanks
